# ‘can’ or ‘could’ in a statistical proposition

Tags: word-usage

Relating specifically to a statical/data based use, ie

- ‘ the assessment of motor function and cognitive testing can identify a specific pattern of problems that can indicate conditions such as MS’

–
what would be the preferred form, ‘can’ or ‘could’, when the outcome is unknown?

Comment: The common thread in academic writing is the 'too fancy for your own good' issue: **assessment** of motor function and cognitive **testing**. You are assessing one thing, but testing another?

Comment: *Can* states fact, *could* states possibility. Can the testing identify a pattern, and can results indicate MS or not?

Comment: Depends if the tests exist and can be conducted now, as well as if they work. Definitely don't like two cans or coulds in the same sentence like that - you need to clearly indicate the relationship between the two.

Comment: 'Can' shows that the test is not infallible; 'could' means that the testing was in the past or (as Stuart says, I believe) has yet to be implemented.

Comment: can=is able to /could=there is a possibility it can

Comment: The word "could" means "is able to" but it is *also* the past tense of "can". So if you intend to discuss the present and not the past, it's better to avoid "could". Also: I do not understand what kind of "outcome" is "unknown".

Answer (score 1):

"the assessment of motor function and cognitive testing can identify a specific pattern of problems that can indicate conditions such as MS’ "

You would use **can** to indicate *capability*:

> Cognitive testing and the assessment of motor function can identify a specific pattern of problems that may indicate conditions such as MS.

You would use **could** to indicate some kind of *counterfactuality*. For example, let's say that insurance companies don't cover such testing and assessment and as a result they're used very little:

> Cognitive testing and motor function assessment **could** be beneficial on a much larger scale *if  only insurance companies would pay for them so they would be used more often*.